# PHP & JSON - Accessing Data

Tags: php, json

I'm building a JSON array as follows:

```
 $footerSEOArray[$data['domainname']] = $data[$language];
 echo json_encode($footerSEOArray);
```

Once passed back I decode it like this:

```
 $footerLinks = json_decode($result);
```

I can print the array as follows:

```
 print_r($footerLinks);
```

And when printed it looks like this:

```
    stdClass Object
 (
[www.data1.com] => Australia
[www.data2.com] => Hindu
[www.data3.com] => Laos
[www.data4.com] => Iranian
[www.data5.com] => America
)
```

Now I need to be able to print the first and second parts of the array but I can't seem to get it to print outside of the print_r();

thx

Comment: It is an object not an array. you should learn how to access object property or array items.

Comment: `$footerLinks` is an **object**. You probably want to get it as array, for which you have to pass `true` as second parameter to `json_decode`. You can then iterate over the array.

Comment: You should be using echo $footerLinks[0]->{'www.data1.com'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass to json_decode an additional parameter to obtain an array instead that a generic array.

```
 $footerLinks = json_decode($result, true);
```

Reference: The php manual [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) page

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the second parameter to the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. It's default behaviour is to convert key-value pairs to the stdClass object, but with this parameter you force using associative table instead.

So:

```
 $footerLinks = json_decode($result, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$footerLinks = (array) $footerLinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

As all said $footerlinks is an object , if you want to use it like an array you've to decode like this:

```
 $footerLinks = json_decode($result,true);
```

Now, $footLinks becomes an associative array.